# How to see every controller & action method called in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been working on many projects developed in ASP.Net MVC by someone else. A lot of time I want to see which controllers & actions were called during a page load while debugging something. Normally I would just set a breakpoint in the controller and then go from there to the views to see if it contains any RenderAction / RenderPartial methods etc. and then set a breakpoint there also. What I am interested in finding out is if there is any tool or way that can show me all the controllers and actions that were called. Ideally I would want to click on some hyper link or just do a page refresh and see a list of each controller & action that was called in sequence. This would be awesome in debugging!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **Glimpse**, this is an open source to diagnostics platform for web.

**URL:** http://getglimpse.com/

**Extensions for MVC and Web forms:** http://getglimpse.com/Extensions/

**Documentation:** http://getglimpse.com/Docs/

[image: Sample]

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)  open source