# ASP.NET MVC: Is it possible to browse all public functions inside a contoller, like in ASMX

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, asmx

If you open an ASMX file in a browser, it shows you a nice summary of all of its functions.

Is it possible to do the same for all public functions in ASP.NET MVC controller ?

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583278/getting-all-controllers-and-actions-names-in-c-sharp

Comment: I didn't mean to do it grammatically.  I meant I'd like to open a controller in a browser and see all of its functions.

Comment: If you can see the controller from the view, it isn't technically a controller. :)

Answer (score 1):

**No, not from a browser.**

The whole point of having a controller is to control what is displayed in the view. The controller should not present itself to the browser. By it's very nature a controller is designed to present something else to the browser, namely the *view*:

[image]

You could, however use a tool like [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com) to [get a peak at those public functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101655/how-to-see-every-controller-action-method-called-in-asp-net-mvc).